# Import Curl data to excel

Tags: json, excel, curl, cryptocurrency

I have this curl:

```
curl -d '{
    "id": "1",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "GetBalance",
    "params": ["zil1qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq9yf6pz"]
}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "https://api.zilliqa.com/"
```

result:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "balance": "3350139612804353762313",
        "nonce": 0
    }
}
```

I want to Import balance to an excel file
how do I do this
Usually I use function webservice but in this case I don't know which url is
thank you

Usually I use function webservice but in this case I don't know which url is
thank you

Comment: You can easily extract json items using either Power Query or one of the VBA Json Converters.  For VBA, see [Timm Hall's converter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)